# Load txt from SQL Database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, database

I have a html code with javascript that loads the data from the same directory or a given folder, that's to say the url is just "folder/text.txt".

However, if I want to extract and read this file from a mySQL database named for example exampledb, how can I indicate the new url in my code in order to import the data with Javascript just as I did with a local file?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you interfacing with the MySQL database? JavaScript does not have a native MySQL driver.

Comment: Check my answer, im not too sure if thats what your looking for or if you want to store the actual url of the text file into the database and than just pull the url from the database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a server side programming language to talk with your database, I would strongly recommend PHP or looking into some more advanced technology like Angular.js along side Node.js!

Here is a quick PHP/mysqli example on pulling data and displaying it in a table.
taken from w3

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["firstname"]." ".$row["lastname"]."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

There is several ways to tackle this, that is just a start.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: This will do. Thanks sir!